# Redirect to previous page using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have a login form with URL

```
index.php/Login
```

after login it shows me home page with same URl because i have called the view in
index function of login controller.
Now problem is when i click change password button it redirects to

```
index.php/Login/change_password
```

now if i called `site_url('Login')` from change_password, it redirects me to login page but not back to user home page.

my Login controller code id below

```
  public function index(){

       $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->database();

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $this->load->view('login');

        }
        else
        {

            $this->load->model('user_data');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $data['info'] = $this->user_data->login_user($email,  $this->input->post('password'));
            $this->load->library('session');
            $user = $data['info'];
            $this->session->set_userdata($user);
            $this->load->view('employee_main');

        }
```

Any help will be greatly appricated.

Comment: There should be a condition in Login/index function that determines whether user is logged in or not right? Can you please post that code?

Comment: @nightgaunt i have pasted index function code above , kindly review it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use session

first change:-

```
$this->session->set_userdata($user);
```

to

```
$this->session->set_userdata('myuser_session', $user); //giving a name to detect
```

Then check session is exist

```
public function index(){
  $this->load->library('session');
  if($this->session->userdata('myuser_session')) {
    redirect(site_url());
  }
```

Comment: Thanx for help every one my problem is solved now using session check:)

Answer (score 2):

To redirect back to the homepage, try:

```
redirect(site_url());
```